# How can I manipulate the Audit screen (SM205510) through code

Tags: acumatica

I'm trying to manipulate the Audit screen (SM205510) through code, using a graph object.  The operation of the screen has processes that seem to work when a screen ID is selected in the header.  This is my code to create a new record:

```
Using PX.Data;
Using PX.Objects.SM;

var am = PXGraph.CreateInstance<AUAuditMaintenance>();
AUAuditSetup auditsetup = new AUAuditSetup();
auditsetup.ScreenID = "GL301000";
auditsetup = am.Audit.Insert(auditsetup);

am.Actions.PressSave();
```

Now, when I execute the code above, it creates a record in the AUAuditSetup table just fine - but it doesn't automatically create the AUAuditTable records the way they are auto-generated in the screen (I realize that the records aren't in the database yet) - but how can I get the graph object to auto-generate the AUAuditTable records in the cache the way they are in the screen?

I've tried looking at the source code for the Audit screen - but it just shows blank, like there's nothing there.  I look in the code repository in Visual Studio and I don't see any file for AUAuditMaintenance either, so I can't see any process that I could run in the graph object that would populate those AUAuditTable records.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acumatica support provided this solution, which works beautifully (Hat tip!):

```
var screenID = "GL301000"; //"SO303000";
var g = PXGraph.CreateInstance<AUAuditMaintenance>();
//Set Header Current
g.Audit.Current = g.Audit.Search<AUAuditSetup.screenID>(screenID);

if (g.Audit.Current == null)    //If no Current then insert
{
    var header = new AUAuditSetup();
    header.ScreenID = screenID;
    header.Description = "Test Audit";
    header = g.Audit.Insert(header);
}

foreach (AUAuditTable table in g.Tables.Select())
{
    table.IsActive = true;
    //Sets Current for Detail
    g.Tables.Current = g.Tables.Update(table);
    foreach (AUAuditField field in g.Fields.Select())
    {
        field.IsActive = false;
        g.Fields.Update(field);
    }
}

g.Actions.PressSave();
```

Answer (score 0):

If I had such a need, to manipulate Audit screen records, I'd rather create my own graph and probably generate DAC class. Also I'd add one more column UsrIsArtificial and set it to false by default. And then manage them as ordinary records, but each time I'll add something, I'd set field UsrIsArtificial to false. 
You can hardly find how that records are managed at graph level because that records are created and handled on on Graph level, but on framework level. Also think twice or even more about design, as direct writing into Audit history may cause confusion for users in the system of what was caused by user, and what was caused by your code. From that point of view I would rather add one more additional table, then add confusion to existing one.